# Why is the $L_{2, 1} $ norm not smooth?

Tags: normed-spaces, convex-optimization, matrix-norms

I was reading this [paper](http://www.cis.temple.edu/%7Eyuhong/research/papers/ijcai13b.pdf). I didn't understand why is the $L_{2, 1}$ norm not smooth?

Comment: Related - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3307741.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it's not differentiable when any row of $W$ is zero.
$$\|W\|_{2,1} = \sum_i \left( \sum_j w_{ij}^2 \right)^{1/2}$$
When it is defined, the partial derivative with respect to an individual element of $W$ is
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial w_{ij}} \|W\|_{2,1} = w_{ij} \left( \sum_k w_{ik}^2 \right)^{-1/2}$$