# Why Is the $ {L}_{2,1} $ Mixed Norm Non Smooth?

Tags: matrices, analysis, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, matrix-analysis

I'm reading about optimization problems involving mixed norms. In particular I'm getting acquainted with the $\ell_{2,1}$ norm. For a matrix $\mathbf{X}$, the $\ell_{\alpha,\beta}$ norm, $\|\mathbf{A}\|_{\alpha,\beta}$ is defined as,

$$\|\mathbf{A}\|_{\alpha,\beta} = \big( \sum_i \|\mathbf{A}_i\|_\alpha^\beta \big)^{\frac{1}{\beta}}$$

where, $\mathbf{A}_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $\mathbf{A}$. According to this definition, $\mathbf{A}_{2,1}$ can be written as,

$$\|\mathbf{A}\|_{2,1} = \sum_i \|\mathbf{A}_i\|_2$$

Now my question is, why is the $\ell_{2,1}$ norm non-smooth? As far as I understand, smoothness of a function is related to continuous differentiability. Is there any reason that even if the $\ell_2$ norm is differentiable a sum of $\ell_2$ norms is non-differentiable. So in short, my question is, why $\ell_{2,1}$ norm is non-smooth? Can it be proved to be a non-smooth function? Will appreciate your help in understanding these concepts.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

The definition as given by [Yale Chang](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bcb7/c8fe81ba5adbfe245480539bfe61bdfd9157.pdf) actually states
$$\|\mathbf{M}\|_{\alpha,\beta} = \left( \sum_i \|m_i\|_\alpha^\beta \right)^{\frac{1}{\beta}} = \left( \sum_i \left( \sum_j \|\mathbf{M}_{i,j}\|^\alpha \right)^\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \right)^\frac{1}{\beta}.$$

Accordingly, the $L_{1,2}$-norm goes as follows.

$$\|\mathbf{M}\|_{2,1} = \sum_i \left( \sum_j \mathbf{M}_{i,j}^2 \right)^{1/2},$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial m_{ij}} \|\mathbf{M}\|_{2,1} = \mathbf{M}_{i,j} \left( \sum_k \mathbf{M}_{i,k}^2 \right)^{-1/2}.$$
Which diverges if any **row is zero**, and thus $L_{1,2}$ is **not differentiable**.
A similar question and great answer from the awesome [Michael Grant](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/52878/michael-grant) can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/847780/why-is-l21-norm-not-smooth/).